# Database getting updated through all the service methods marked read only by spring transaction management

Tags: spring

I am learning spring transaction management.
I have used Spring3.0 and oracle 10g for practice.
Following is my spring transaction configuration

```
 <aop:config>
      <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* com.spring.*.service.impl.*.*(..))" 
                    id="serivcePointcut"/>
      <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="serivcePointcut"/>
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
     <tx:attributes>
         <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
         <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true"/>
         <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice.
```

I just wanted to check whether inserting any record through get* method will throw exception as read-only has been marked true.So I inserted a record through getCustomer() method. But guess what instead of throwing exception the record got inserted.

In the logs I am able to see transaction being created for com.spring.customer.service.impl.CustomerServiceImpl.Even the log shows Setting jdbc connection read only.

Can anyone explain where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc of [TransactionDefinition](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition.html#isReadOnly%28%29) says:

> This just serves as a hint for the actual transaction subsystem; it
>   will not necessarily cause failure of write access attempts. A
>   transaction manager which cannot interpret the read-only hint will not
>   throw an exception when asked for a read-only transaction.

And the javadoc of [Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setReadOnly%28boolean%29) says:

> Puts this connection in read-only mode as a hint to the driver to
>   enable database optimizations.

In short, using readOnly might enhance the performance if your code is indeed read-only. But that won't prevent you from doind write operations in such a transaction.